# Router to router connection failing, long cable

Tags: networking, router, lan, cable, cabling

Here is the scenario:

- Router 1 is plugged in to a modem in its "wide area network" (WAN) port.
- I connect one of Router 1's "local area network" (LAN) ports to Router 2's WAN port via a very long CAT 6 cable (around 90 meters).
- Router 2 fails to detect the connection; it insists that there is no cable connected to its WAN port.

I tried many things, including different router brands
(Netgear, TP-Link, ...), and eventually I discovered that if I do the same Router 1 LAN port to Router 2 WAN port connection using a 1 meter cable, everything works as expected.

What to do?

I am asking and answering this question as it could have saved me a few hours of my life if someone had asked it before.

Comment: It can be: wrong router (instance, not model), wrong/damaged cable (twisted, crushed, short, open, etc., during laying, for example), wrong/damaged jack/socket.

Answer (score 1):

So the problem seems to be that routers nowadays expect cable length to WAN ports to be small.

The solution for me was to use a good enough switch (TP-Link's TL-SG105 in my case) to sit between Router 1 and Router 2, so the setup is now

- Modem ← 1 m cable → Router 1 WAN port
- Router 1 LAN port ← 90 m cable → Switch port 1
- Switch port 2 ← 1 m cable → Router 2 WAN port

Comment: Well, the standard maximum length for Gigabit Ethernet copper cables _is_ 100 meters, so it's not very surprising that a poor-quality router or switch can't handle cables so close to the limit.

Comment: *Routers nowadays expect cable length to WAN ports to be small* Each router's port MUST meet the standards. So WAN cable length restriction is doubt.

Comment: Is there any evidence the 90 meter cable is not faulty and properly terminated at both ends? Also (and speculatively) could there be an interference problem/shielding issue with the cable - is it run alongside power for example?