# Second router not sensing internet while PC connected with the same cable does

Tags: router, lan, wan

Because I have my main router (from my internet provider ) in the corner of the house, WiFi doesn't reach my room (thick walls). I connected my PC with a UTP cable about 25-30 meters long. Now, a few years later, I bought a second router for the WiFi signal to reach closer rooms, but the router (TL-MR3420) doesn't 'sense' an internet signal in the cable. The blinking orange LED indicates internet, but it never turns green. With the same cable I have internet on my pc with no problems. I also checked with a short 30 cm cable straight from the main router and the green LED appears after a second. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Be sure to connect the cable from the ISP router to the LAN ports on the new router and not the WAN port. If you connect to the WAN port, you'll likely need to configure it accordingly, etc. when it's connected to another routers LAN ports. So connect new router than LAN to LAN ports only and all should be good. If not, tell the make and model of both routers and explain which ports you have connected the Ethernet cable.

Comment: Im using ips LAN to WAN, as i told in my post. same cable connected to my pc is working, when i switch it to second router nothing. When i connect second router in same way with short 30 cm cable, everything is working.

Comment: i found similar problem w/o answer https://superuser.com/questions/1427323/router-to-router-connection-failing-long-cable

Comment: I'd have to see if probably to better understand your configuration but Googling the new TL-MR3420 router, you want to plug whatever Internet cable works from the PC when you plug it into the PC into that new router's [yellow LAN ports](https://i.imgur.com/es9qodU.png). I suspect you have that plugged into the blue port and then your PC plugged into the yellow. Plug both your PC and the Internet connection into the yellow ports and see if that is what you need. Essentially your router will be a switch rather than a router and the WAN blue port will stay unused.

Comment: But if you must plug the router from LAN to WAN, then you will need to log into the router and configure it's IP settings similar to how you have those configured on the PC that works that way. Usually you will hard code the IP address of the devices connected to the WAN ports and confirm they are subnet configured and such to work on that network segment. If you are just plugging it all in and expecting it to just work, then use LAN ports. Again, I'd need to better understand maybe with a diagram or better explanation of each connection that does work and the correlated IP configs.

Comment: Oh god, you still talking about things you don't understand. Don't wast your time.
R1 LAN ----30mcable ----> PC, Wroks ||
R1 Lan ----- 30m cable ----- >R2 WAN, doesn't work ||
R1 Lan -- 30 cm cable ---- >R2 WAN, works   same settings like above.||
R1 Lan ---30 m cable --->R2 lan doesnt work (settingsa for lan[DHCP & NAT off])||
R1 Lan ---30 cm cable --->R2 lan  Works same settings like above.||
This is called magic. 
just checked on 10m cable and works too, but FTP instead of UDP.